# Lost Kensington lock key - how to remove from laptop?

Tags: physical-security, kensington-lock

I'm asking this only for curiosity.

Suppose I lost my Kensington lock key: how to take my laptop with me?

Part 1 of the process is breaking the cable with heavy scissors, the ones also used by gardeners to prune bushes, or even better one like the following:
[image: heavy scissors or whatever you call it]

This allows to bring laptop home, at least...

This leaves the lock still attached to laptop, and here comes part 2 of the process: how to remove the final piece of Kensington from laptop in order to replace it with the newly purchased one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen that you can open these (and similar) locks relatively simply with a piece of cardboard!

http://youtu.be/0SkKJ4yOKo8

Embarrassingly, I have a need to do this myself, as I've lost a laptop key.

I'll report back whether or not this actually works (I'm not sure if mine is a Kensington or a cheap knock-off, to be honest- if this doesn't work, I may have to use the angle-grinder!)

Comment: Ooh.  Just came across this and remembered that I said I'd report back.

I couldn't get it to work, so it had to be the angle grinder.  It may be that I was using the wrong grade of cardboard or something.

Comment: Looks like the video is now unavailable.